# How can I search in more than 1 xml file and return result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, asp-classic

I'm currently doing simple catalogue (using webpage). My database only XML file (my boss doesn't want a database). I managed to get single result and from single XML file and display it. My only problem now is that I will have several XML file from several categories/group.

Can we search using jQuery from various XML file ?

My JavaScript Function from a listing i will click and it will display 1     result from xml row

```
// Choose Part based from listing 
function choosePartCat(searchParam,searchUrl){
    $.ajax({
        url:searchUrl,
        dataType:"xml",
        type:"GET",
        success:displayItemList

    });
}

function displayItemList(data){
    var list = document.getElementById('rowshow');

    var heading = "<ul id='rowshow'>";
    var indexChasis = 1;
    $(data).find("motopart").each(function() {
        heading =  heading+"<li class='CMSListMenuLI'><a href='#' onclick='chooseItem(&apos;"+$(this).find("partno").text()+"&apos;,&apos;"+$(this).find("desc").text()+"&apos;,&apos;"+$(this).find("desc").text()+"&apos;)'>"+$(this).find("partno").text()+"</a></li>";
        //heading =  heading+"<li class='CMSListMenuLI'><a href='#' class='opener'>"+$(this).find("partno").text()+"</a></li>";
        indexChasis = indexChasis + 1;
    });
    heading = heading + "</ul>"
    list.innerHTML = heading;
    $("#showHideTableItem").css('display','none');
}
```

Comment: <category1>
  <motopart>
    <partno>Chasis_3311_xml</partno>
    <desc>Gary Moore</desc>
    <price>UK</price>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
  </motopart>
</category1>

Comment: No, you can only make one request to a one file at a time. You would need to repeat this code for every XML file. Trying to do this as you are is going to be slow, hard to maintain and just generally awful for your users. A database is by far the best way to do this. I can't see why your boss wouldn't want to use one, other than ignorance.

Comment: @Jerza Please use the [edit] link below your question to add more information rather than posting it in the comments where it can be overlooked or hard to read.  I agree with Rory in that searching multiple XML files would be slow and error prone.  You can load XML data into a database and search that however, but even that is slower than having things loaded into database tables as data rather than XML